# Is this a typo on my book?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

[image]

See (6.74). I believe this is a type as I got this constraint to be

$$ \pi_1 + \pi_3 = -1 $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a typo.

You have written down the constraint correctly, they can be read off as the coefficient of $x_3$ in the maximization problem.